# In my Compute Engine VM I have to reinstall Python modules every time I log in

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The title says it all. I have a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM and every time I have to login, in order to run my script I have to reinstall the packages every time.

It doesn't matter if I have the modules installed in the virtual environment 
or in the VM

The weird thing is that the .json credentials that I supposed to export every time are fine. I don't have to export every time I login.

Any ideas why this keep happening?

Comment: Check that Python is still installed on re-login. You might just have a PATH problem.

Comment: A path problem was my thought as well.  Be sure to also check PYTHONPATH variable.

Comment: Going to check it right now

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are describing matches with the [limitations of Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations). I'm not saying you are connecting the the GCP Cloud Shell instead of your VM Instance, however some users have confused his VMs terminals with Cloud Shell in the past.

Is this only happening for Python or any other package? Please review you have enough space available in your Filesystems and that you are not installing the package in a volatile Filesystem partition.